# Burninate tag to get out of this [bind]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I'm looking at the [bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bind) tag, and here's what the tag wiki excerpt says:

> This tag means different things in different contexts; consider using
>   less ambiguous tags instead. Common meanings include:
>
> - BIND the DNS server (named)
> - the `bind` method in jQuery
> - the `bind` function in socket programming
> - For `boost::bind` in C++, use [boost-bind]
> - Do not use this tag just to say that you're binding something to something else.

The excerpt itself advises against the use of this tag. In the tag wiki, there's a long list of things that this tag applies to.

Related: [unbind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unbind)

---

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? And is it unambiguous?**
Big NO.

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
Yes, it is, in most cases. Questions about DNS server binding are, however, off topic.

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**
Based on the wide applicability to various software, this doesn't seem like a great meta tag. I'm open to correction though.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
No, it could refer to a principle, a software, a function, or method, depending on the context. It does, however, imply something is bound to something else (however the wiki explicitly advises against using the tag just to describe that).

---

Based on the boxes ticked above, and seeing as (almost) every question (from what I've seen) is on topic, perhaps we can disambiguate the tag, or just burninate it completely because I do not see it adding any value as a tag.

Comment: "Is the concept described even on-topic for the site? Yes, it does" How it does? The you say that the tag itself is ambiguous. How could all its meanings be on topic?

Comment: @Braiam Yes, because even if a tag is ambiguous, the concepts it describes (i.e., programming related as per the tag wiki), are still very much on topic.

Comment: Wait, the DNS server BIND is definitively not on topic for the most common task: serving DNS entries.

Comment: @Braiam Ah, nice catch, did not think that through :) Updated.

Comment: I don't see any need for any action on this suggestion. There are many meanings of 'bind' in IT, and nearly all of them are on-topic here. I'm surprised to find that the tag-wiki list was very incomplete, now somewhat less so, and that some of the associated concepts like COSNaming didn't have their own tags. I suggest that disambiguating the [tag:bind] tag will just give us a dozen new tags that won't get used, and I don't see any reason to just remove the tag.

Comment: @EJP being on topic does not necessarily imply the tag is appropriate here. The tag is waaaay too broad to be useful in any context, and there are a motley bunch of questions under this tag that have nothing to do with each other. There surely must be a better course of action than inaction.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ *Non sequitur.* Sometimes masterly inaction is exactly the right course of action. You haven't addressed my last sentence in any way.

Comment: @EJP not really, what I was trying to say was that the tag is a mess, and needs cleaning. If the usage cannot be disambiguated, then let it be removed because *it adds no value as a tag*.

Comment: Burninate tag to get out of this [bind]

Comment: Can you consider each usage on a case-by-case basis, for tag disambiguation, is there an existing tag we should use, or make the case for tag deletion for that particular case. Btw, jQuery bind is deprecated in favor of `.on()`. But there's already a tag [event-binding], should use that, for that sense? Also you might like to mention the sense [key-binding].

Comment: I thought the tag was about Haskell's `>>=` bind operator...

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Speaking of that, there are 17 questions tagged with both \[haskell\] and \[bind\]. In 15 of them, \[bind\] can be replaced or subsumed by \[monad\], as it refers to `>>=` in those cases.